# align-items: center; not working on truncated menu

Tags: html, css

I am currently practicing my responsive design skills, and am running into an error that I don't understand. When the device screen is below 768px I want it do display icons instead of the of the normal navbar. I want these icons to be vertically centered. However, when I run the code below on a full screen the navbar is vertically centered, but when you shrink to mobile size the icons are not vertically centered. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Colmar Academy</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION -->
    <div id="navbar">
        <div class="brand">
            <img src="assets/images/ic-logo.svg" alt="Logo">
            <h1><span class="special">COLMAR</span>ACADEMY</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <a href="#"><li>On campus</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Online</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>For companies</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>Sign in</li></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="truncated-menu">
            <img src="assets/images/ic-logo.svg" alt="Logo">
            <img src="assets/images/ic-on-campus.svg" alt="On campus">
            <img src="assets/images/ic-online.svg" alt="Online">
            <img src="assets/images/ic-login.svg" alt="Sign in">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* GENERAL */
html {
    background-color: #000;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.brand {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 24px;
    align-items: center;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

.menu li {
    margin-left: 16px;
}

.truncated-menu {
    display: none;
}

/* Mobile responsive design */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .brand {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .truncated-menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 64%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: set height 64px instead of 64%.

Answer (score 0):

This was my error height should have been 64px not 64%.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .truncated-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

Set the height to 64px (what you intended) and add margin/padding: 0 to the .truncated-menu class. Default margin and padding are actually what breaks this layout. Good luck!